# WinHttpHandler And System.Net.Http Incompatible

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `WinHttpHandler 4.4.0 (latest stable version)` but apparently it requires `System.Net.Http version 4.2.0.0` which is nowhere to be found on my system. I tried installing the Nuget but its version is `4.1.1.1`. I upgraded to `.Net 4.7` and the `System.Net.Http.dll` version under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7` is `4.0.0.0`. So where can I find the version `4.2.0.0` to reference?

Comment: Open the nuGet console and do: `Install-Package System.Net.Http -Version 4.3.2`. This should get you the latest version which is 4.3.2 indeed.

Comment: @Hubbs It has dll version 4.1.1.1